# what's the formula to adjust a number so a given cell is always > 0?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i'm working on a google spreadsheet using fairly simple formulas.

[image]

i'm trying to get "Q to sell" to automatically calculate so that "equality" is always TRUE. the goal is to have the sheet find the min quantity i need to sell to cover the expenses. the formula for equality is gross-expenses.

another way to ask is what is the formula to find a number that keeps X TRUE?

Comment: Would it not be easier to put the formula `=ceiling(F2/B2)` into the Q to Sell column? (Where F2 is the first cell under "Expenses" and B2 is the first cell under "Sell P")

Comment: @nwill001 perfect i think this did it! can you just explain in plain english what this did? thank you!

Comment: Math: B2*x=F2 => x = F2/B2, the ceiling rounds up

Comment: I added an answer with a description of what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the formula =ceiling(F2/B2) into the Q to Sell column? (Where F2 is the first cell under "Expenses" and B2 is the first cell under "Sell P")

This simply calculates Expenses divided by Sell P to find the Quantity that you would need to sell. This would equal a decimal so we use the `=ceiling()` function to round that up to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `CEILING` function:

[image]